# App crashes when switching from activity 1 to activity 2

Tags: java, android

In my app, there are so many activities which are referred to as levels. And one activity is Reward activity. when i win level-1, reward activity opens. Now i want to replay the level-1. For this i have used getExtra(). My app crashes when i click the replay button.

Houselevel1.java

```
 public void getReward(){
    if(count == 3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.creatives.arfa.revealthesecretsgame.Reward");
        intent.putExtra("activity", "level1");
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

HouseLevel2.java

```
    public void getReward(){
    if(count == 3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.creatives.arfa.revealthesecretsgame.Reward");
        intent.putExtra("activity", "level2");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Reward.java

```
  public void replayLevel() {
    replay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.replay);
    Intent intent= getIntent();
    activity = intent.getStringExtra("activity");
    replay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View paramView) {
            if(activity.equals("level2")){
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.creatives.arfa.revealthesecretsgame.HouseLevel2");
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if(activity.equals("level1")){
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.creatives.arfa.revealthesecretsgame.Houselevel1");
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What says the log?

Comment: show us your stacktrace please

Comment: Is the lowercase `l` in `Houselevel1` a typo?

Comment: This is how you move from one content to another!!!                                            Intent intent = new Intent(this, "com.creatives.arfa.revealthesecretsgame.Reward");
        intent.putExtra("activity", "level1");
        startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the java code you've posted, in the `Reward.java` file, you're trying to create another Intent Object with the same name as the one declared in the scope right above it. Because of this, the build will never be successful.

Also, when you declare intents, you MUST pass on the `activity_name.class` file.

Something you can try:

1) HouseLevel1.java

```
public void getReward(){
    if(count == 3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.creatives.arfa.revealthesecretsgame.Reward.class);
        intent.putExtra("activity", "level1");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

2) HouseLevel2.java

```
public void getReward(){
    if(count == 3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.creatives.arfa.revealthesecretsgame.Reward.class);
        intent.putExtra("activity", "level2");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

3) Reward.java

```
public void replayLevel() {
    replay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.replay);
    Intent intent= getIntent();
    activity = intent.getStringExtra("activity");
    replay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View paramView) {
            if(activity.equals("level2")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.creatives.arfa.revealthesecretsgame.HouseLevel2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else if(activity.equals("level1")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.creatives.arfa.revealthesecretsgame.Houselevel1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Also, if you're simply using the `Reward.java` file to get the previous intent's data, perform some calculation, and send some data back to the calling, or parent activity, then you can simply use the `startActivityForResult()` method, which takes care what what you're trying to do manually.

Here's a small article that might be able to help you with the problem

> http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html#retrieving-result-data-from-a-sub-activity

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is go from Activity 1 or to 2 to a Reward activity grab something and send that something back to either activity.
What you do is *startActivityForResult* You pass an Id (constant number) do what you do on the Reward activty, pack what you need to return in a Bundle, and set ActivtyResult to OK and close your activity.
Your app will go back to the Activity1 or 2 whoever call it. On those activties you override the method onActivityResult There you check if the id on which the result is coming from is the Id you sent on the startActivityForResult and if the status is OK.
Then you have whatever was set on the Reward activity. The Reward activity don't need to know from where it came from if only will grab some data. So you can later have an Activity3 that calls the Reward activity and you do not need to modify the Reward activity.
It is explain here check the accepted answer.
[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android#10407371)